# Formik validation using Yup plus specific validation via api call

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I'm using Formik for a form that will be used to create a user. Validating form values using a Yup validation schema.

However, I also need to check whether the username is valid via an api call as the user fills out the form (not just on submission). I can set *errors* collection manually if the api call returns that the username is taken, but this is subsequently cleared as the field in question passes its Yup validation (which just checks for length).

What's the best approach for this apart from just managing the check in React and preventing form submission if (say) a state flag is set?

====================================================

Ok, I figured it out. I used [.test](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestname-string-message-string--function-test-function-schema) and as this accepts a validator function that returns a promise I could use that for my async call.

Custom errors created using createError (see docs).

All the best

Mark